# Numpy: Extract particular rows in matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix W and two vectors y1 and y2. I want to extract rows from W. The rows I am interested in are in the range [y1:y2]. What is the best way of doing this in Numpy? **Can this be done without using any for-loops or map method**? For e.g.:

```
W = [[   1.,    2.,    3.,    4.],
 [   5.,    6.,    7.,    8.],
 [   9.,   10.,   11.,   12.],
 [  13.,   21.,   33.,   41.],
 [  55.,   66.,   74.,   83.],
 [  92.,  106.,  711.,  142.],
 [  19.,   27.,   33.,   24.],
 [  54.,   66.,   74.,   38.],
 [  29.,  210.,  131.,  412.]]

y1 = [[0],
 [0],
 [6],
 [3]]

y2 = [[3],
 [3],
 [9],
 [6]]

I want w[y1:y2,:] ., i.e.

newW = [[   1.,    2.,    3.,    4.],
 [   5.,    6.,    7.,    8.],
 [   9.,   10.,   11.,   12.],
 [   1.,    2.,    3.,    4.],
 [   5.,    6.,    7.,    8.],
 [   9.,   10.,   11.,   12.],
 [  19.,   27.,   33.,   24.],
 [  54.,   66.,   74.,   38.],
 [  29.,  210.,  131.,  412.],
 [  13.,   21.,   33.,   41.],
 [  55.,   66.,   74.,   83.],
 [  92.,  106.,  711.,  142.]]
```

Comment: Can you edit the code so that it can be copied into a python console?

Comment: What's wrong with using for or list comprehension?

Comment: I am using this in a place where I cannot use for-loops or list comprehensions but only matrix operations including indexing operations. I am using something similar to this in a neural network based architecture and I have calculate some gradients which will be tricky with for loops or list comprehensions.

Comment: Are you using theano or something equivalent? In that case it may be more prudent to ask the question there, because there is probably a way out that is specific to that package. If you ask the question with the numpy tag, then despite you rrestrictions, the useful answer is making a list of indices ...

Comment: Thanks I have done that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the slices for yourself as indices and then use them:

```
indices = np.concatenate([np.arange(iy1, iy2) for iy1, iy2 in zip(y1.ravel(), y2.ravel())]
newW = w[indices]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use a list comprehension to generate the indexes, then you can use:

```
w[np.array([np.arange(i,j) for i,j in np.hstack((y1,y2))]).ravel()]
```

If you really can't use loops, try:

```
a = np.hstack((y1,y2))
func = lambda i: np.arange(a[i][0],a[i][1])
b = np.vectorize(func,otypes=[np.ndarray])
w[np.hstack(b(np.arange(4)))]
```

Comment: As I already wrote, I cannot use list comprehensions, with list comprehensions its pretty obvious, how to do it.